# My cocoa powder won't mix with melted butter

Tags: baking, cocoa

I was trying to mix cocoa powder into melted butter but instead of mixing in it had a grainy texture and wouldn't dissolve. The butter was still hot and it was only melted not boiled.

I use Heintz cocoa powder which I have used before with no problems.

I am however using a new kind of butter. Can increased moisture content or fat content in the butter cause this?

Comment: What do you mean by "mixing"? Cocoa powder, from what I've read here, does not dissolve, so it's going to stay grainy.

Comment: @Catija I may be wrong but my understanding is that cocoa powder doesn't dissolve in water. If that is correct, the water content of the butter could possibly make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, cocoa powder doesn't "dissolve"; it just becomes an emulsion in the carrier. Changing the water/fat content of the carrier could certainly change whether the cocoa particles stick together or spread out, changing whether they emulsify.